# Exception breakpoint in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, breakpoints, appdelegate

I have added an exception breakpoint to my XCode project, and every time I run the app, it breaks at the line

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
```

I have no breakpoint set anywhere in the code, see screenshot below. If I click *continue program execution* it will go on to run the app as it should. Is this supposed to happen?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Breakpoints are supposed to stop execution where they are set. If you type c in console log the program will continue. The fact is stops exec and acts like an exception error is the normal behaviour. Simply remove breakpoint so it should be not called. It does not really matter where you set up breakpoints. If you ser up one in Appdelegate it should throw an exec error in main (ussualy with arg).

Comment: Updated the question with a screenshot of my breakpoints. I have removed them all, but it still breaks at this line.

Answer (score 0):

Add Ex.BreakPoint see this image and follow instruction
[image]

i hope here is your solution

Comment: I don't think you understand my question, I'm already using an exception breakpoint. I'm just trying to figure out why the exception is thrown at that line.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it was resolved after I have deinstalled `Cocoapods` from my project, renamed scheme, removed old `.xcworkspace`, and then installed `Cocoapods` again. New `.xcworkspace` was created and fantom breakpoint never appeared.